# The opposite of append in this table using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unobtrusive-javascript

I need the opposite to this peice of code:

```
if( $('#effort_<%= @project_task.id %>').length == 0 )
  $('#task_list').append('<tr><td><%= @project_task.project.project_number %> <%= @project_task.project.project_name %> - <%= @project_task.task_name %></td>' +
                         '<td><%= text_field :effort, :hours, :name => 'effort_' + @project_task.id.to_s, :id => 'effort_' + @project_task.id.to_s %></td>' +
                         '<td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/delete.png'), :method => :destroy, :remote => true %></td></tr>' );
  $('#effort_<%= @project_task.id.to_s %>').change( function() { submiteffort( this, <%= @project_task.id.to_s %>); } );
```

when the user clicks the delete button it needs to delete that row of the table.
I know you can use .remove() but im not sure how to use this since im new to RoR.

Comment: RoR output html so you can use jquery normaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#task_list a").live("click", function(event) {
  $(event.target).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Make sure you use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). `parents` will return all the ancestor `tr`s so it might remove more nodes than needed if you have nested tables. `closest` is the safest option.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your delete is inside the tr for each of the rows you need to do something like this

if the close buttton/image has a class close then bind an event on it like this

```
$('close').live("click",function()
{
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();   //this here is referring to the button 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how you want to do. I hope you dont mind but I've stripped it down to bare bones but it should give you a good idea of where to begin.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/saceh/1/

```
<button id="Add">Add Row</button>
<hr>
<table id="TaskList">
</table>

<script>
// RowId is not important, just used to show you that rows are dynamically added
var RowId = 0;

$("#Add").click(function (e) {
    $("#TaskList").append("<tr><td>" + RowId  + "</td><td><button id='Delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
    RowId++;
});

$("#Delete").click(function(e) {
   var Row = $(this).parents('tr');
   $(Row).remove(); 
});
```

When delete is clicked it finds the parent row and removes it and Add does something similar to what you are doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method (add some identifiers) to point to the row you want to delete and than use the [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to actually remove it.